# Which of the following regular expressions generate(s) no string with two consecutive 1’s?

Tags: regular-expressions

This is a GRE practice question.

Which of the following regular expressions generate(s) no string with two consecutive 1’s? (Note that ε denotes the empty string.)

I. (1 + ε)(01 + 0)*

II. (01+10)*

III. (0+1)*(0+ε)

(A) I only

(B) II only

(C) III only

(D) I and II only

(E) II and III only

My understanding is that neither I nor III generates strings with `11`. In I, a string containing `1` is either `1` or `1` surrounded by `0`'s. In III, all `1`'s are preceded by `0`'s. But the correct answer is A, so III must generate a string with `11` somehow. Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: "In III, all 1's are preceded by 0's" are you sure? Try some examples of $(0+1)^*$ (what is the meaning of $(0+1)$?)

Comment: What *is* the meaning of plus? Usually it is one or more times, but then it is written in superscript. Is it just regular concatenation? No, must be or...

Comment: Isn't this a bit localized anyway?

Comment: It would be nice if the question could be put in more general terms.

Comment: Thank you! I did confuse the meaning of +. I thought it was concatenation; it was union. I agree it's a pretty specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

III is $(0+1)^* (0+ \epsilon)$ which means pick a word from $\Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma = \{0, 1 \}$ and then concatenate it with either $0$ or $\epsilon$.

so III Does generate a string with two consecutive $1$'s. In fact it generates every string which contains $1$'s, $0$'s or is empty.

Answer (score -1):

A is correct only.
In II:0110 string present which has two consecutive 11
In III also 11 contain from (0+1)* expression...

Comment: I don't see what this adds over the other answer, which makes the same point more clearly.